# How CSS works correctly in Internet Explorer

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer

I use below CSS to make button more attractive.

It works fine Google Chrome but in Internet Explorer it just shows the colored box.

How I make this CSS useful in Internet Explorer.

```css
button {
  background: #eb0505;
  background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #eb0505, #b82b2b);
  background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #eb0505, #b82b2b);
  background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #eb0505, #b82b2b);
  background-image: -o-linear-gradient(top, #eb0505, #b82b2b);
  background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, #eb0505, #b82b2b);
  -webkit-border-radius: 28;
  -moz-border-radius: 28;
  border-radius: 28px;
  font-family: Georgia;
  color: #ffffff;
  font-size: 20px;
  padding: 10px 20px 10px 20px;
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<button>Button</button>
```

Please help.

Comment: Which version of IE are you using?

Comment: @TalentRunners its Internet Explorer 11

Answer (score 0):

But your code is working fine in IE11, for IE 9 you can use this:

```
background: #eb0505;
filter:  progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorStr='#eb0505', EndColorStr='#b82b2b');
-ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorStr='#eb0505', EndColorStr='#b82b2b')";
  background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #eb0505, #b82b2b);
  background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #eb0505, #b82b2b);
  background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #eb0505, #b82b2b);
  background-image: -o-linear-gradient(top, #eb0505, #b82b2b);
  background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, #eb0505, #b82b2b);
  -webkit-border-radius: 28;
  -moz-border-radius: 28;
  border-radius: 28px;
  font-family: Georgia;
  color: #ffffff;
  font-size: 20px;
  padding: 10px 20px 10px 20px;
  text-decoration: none;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 button {
          background: #eb0505;
          border-radius: 28px;
          font-family: Georgia;
          color: #ffffff;
          font-size: 20px;
          padding: 10px 20px 10px 20px;
          text-decoration: none;
        }


<button>Button</button>
```